# What is the inclination angle of a zero vector and an arbitrary vector in 3D? 0 or 90 degrees?

Tags: vectors, 3d, angle

If we have a zero vector and an arbitrary vector, then what is their inclination angle? Since their scalar product is zero, the inclination angle seems to be undefined. Can I say that this angle is zero or there is convention which considers it to be 90°?

Comment: For what purpose do you need to define this?

Comment: @user3716267 I have pairs of vectors whose angle needs to be determined. I should choose the best pair whose angle is as close to 90 degrees as possible. Therefore, if one vector of a pair is zero, it is inconvenient to use 90 degrees for the repated angle. (Inconvenience appears in the formal description of the algorithm.) Does this comment change the answer to my question?

Comment: No; you still haven't described what this angle is going to be *used for*.  What will assigning it to $0$ result in, practically?  There's no obvious mathematical convention here (I think most mathematicians would prefer to leave this undefined, all else being equal).